# BrowserModule has already been loaded , create lazy loading module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular8, angular-routing

Error is :

```
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
    at new BrowserModule
```

Two days i search Internet , not getting fisible solution:

*Add and remove BrowserModule and import CommonModule in NotificationModule no use of it*.

Here See the ScreenShot:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM9ZS.png

I have Two Modules ,

1. AppModule
2. NotificationModule

**My Goal is : I have SearchComponent in app.module , i need to get in notification.module .**

In AppModule i define:

```
imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    CalendarModule,
    PopoverModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    AccordionModule.forRoot(),
    NgxUsefulSwiperModule,
    PickerModule,
    NgxFileDropModule,
    NgxMaterialTimepickerModule,
    PlyrModule,
    NgbModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    ContenteditableModule,
    ScrollEventModule,
    NgxStarsModule,
    NgImageSliderModule,
    NgxImageZoomModule.forRoot(),
    ProgressBarModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule,
    ColorPickerModule,
    NgxBraintreeModule,
    QRCodeModule
  ],
 exports: [
    SearchComponent ,
],
```

Routing AppModule:

```
{ 
        path: 'Notification',
        loadChildren: () => import('./notification/notification.module').then(m => m.NotificationModule) 
    },
```

And My NotificationModule : **here i import app.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppModule } from '../app.module';
import { NotificationRoutingModule } from './notification-routing.module';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
        ListComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule ,
    AppModule ,
    NotificationRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class NotificationModule { }
```

Routing NotificationModule is :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'List',
            component: ListComponent
        }
    ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class NotificationRoutingModule { }
```

Help is really appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is becauase in notification module you import the App module again.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
        ListComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule ,
    AppModule ,// remove this line.
    NotificationRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class NotificationModule { }
```

If there is a need for something in the appmodule then extract it to a separate shared module and import that one.

Comment: thanks @Sandor from your valuable response, so i need to create another one module called sharedModule, here we import SearchComponet(i need SearchComponent From Appmodule)

Comment: thanks @Sandor , my issue is implement lazy loaded module , if we share component , so we implement sharedModule, so that the issue came.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the AppModule from NotificationModule.

Comment: I need SearchComponent in Appmodule , So that i import app.modules , any alternate option ?

Comment: write the component in your in declaration of module, in which module you want to use that component(SearchComponent).

Comment: thanks @surendra , Its caues an error , why means , we import two module same class.

Comment: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type SearchComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and NotificationModule! Please consider moving SearchComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and NotificationModule `

Comment: write the SearchComponent in app.module only.

Comment: then how i get NotificationModule ?, then i export app.module , here our error BrowserModule has already been loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217151/discussion-between-rubin-and-surendra-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

In my case we were using NgxGalleryModule (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kolkov/ngx-gallery). We were getting BrowserModule error in the lazy loaded modules in which this was imported.

We fixed it by doing the following steps:

1. We removed BrowserModule from app.module.ts since we were importing BrowerAnimationsModule which already exports BrowserModule
2. We updated Platform Browser package using npm i @angular/platform-browser
3. We rolled back Ngx Gallery to an older 1.2.3 version since the latest version was still showing the BrowserModule error
4. We made sure that BrowerAnimationsModule was only in app.module.ts

This fixed the error! I hope it helps someone. Updating the Platform Browser is the key step.